# Ruby: Use Mocha to stub HTTP POST requests

Tags: ruby

I want to mock HTTP POST requests with Mocha.  The code to be tested basically looks like

```
req=Net::HTTP::Post.new "whatever"
connection=Net::HTTP.new( "whatever", 80 )
result=connection.request( req ).body
```

Now, if this were Java, I'd hack around this class so I could inject some fake HTTPRequest objects and such, and I'd be ok.  Is that *really* the way I have to do it in Ruby, since apparently no one on the entire Internet has ever done this and posted to tell about a better way to do it?

Comment: Why not https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr/ ?

Comment: Because we already have about 8 squillion gems?

Comment: Also, it doesn't say it supports Mocha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to avoid gems, but I can't say enough good things about https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/ . We had similar pain when trying to use just Mocha to stub/mock network requests. WebMock feels familiar and works great.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because webmock does seem like a Good Thing, although I'm not sure adding it is an option for me in the current context.